# Flowchart Symbol for File Input Output Java

Tags: java, file-io, flowchart

What flowchart symbol should I use for file input and output? Is it still the same as using Scanner? Thanks! (The language is Java btw)

I was thinking maybe the usual Input and Output symbol might work but I'm worried that there could be something else.

Comment: File input and output are input and output operations.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart#Building_blocks) a summary of  American National Standards Institute (ANSI) set standards for flowcharts and their symbols in the 1960s.

[image: rhomboid]

The process of inputting and outputting data, as in entering data or displaying results, is represented as a rhomboid.

[image: quadrilateral]

Manual input is represented by quadrilateral, with the top irregularly sloping up from left to right, like the side view of a keyboard.

[image]

Data file or database is represented by a cylinder symbolizing a disk drive.

[image]

Single documents are represented as a rectangle with a wavy base.